Luna HSM connection establishment from Kubernetes Setup
As you may already know, Luna HSM Clients establish a connection with both certificates and source ip with HSMs. While in the pod based deployment, the ips are dynamic this authentication is not possible.
I'm trying to understand different alternatives that could solve this problem,
One alternative could be, get a dedicated node on kubernetes and there by get a fixed ip which could be a potential solution,
What other alternatives could solve this problem, I'm sure it's not just me facing this issue. If you have faced this and solved please share. Thanks :)
